# can the same code be used for both hadoop and yarn

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have been thinking about this question for a while now. I have been trying to compare the performance of hadoop 1 vs yarn by running the basic word count example. I am still unsure about how the same .jar file can be used to execute on both the frameworks. As far as I understand yarn has a different set of api's which it uses to set connection with resource manager, create an application master etc. 
  So if I develop an application(.jar), can it be run on both the frameworks without any change in code? 
  Also what could be meaningful parameters to differentiate hadoop vs yarn for a particular application?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's clear up some terms here.

**Hadoop** is the umbrella system that contains the various components needed for distributed storage and processing.  I believe the term you're looking for when you say **hadoop 1** is **MapReduce v1 (MRv1)**

**MRv1** is a component of Hadoop that includes the job tracker and task trackers.  It only relies on HDFS.

**YARN** is a component of Hadoop that abstracts out the resource management part of MRv1.

**MRv2** is the mapreduce application rewritten to run on top of YARN.

So when you're asking if **hadoop 1** is interchangeable with **YARN**, you're probably actually asking if **MRv1** is interchangeable with **MRv2**.  And the answer is generally, yes. The Hadoop system knows how to run the same mapreduce application on both mapreduce platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to climbage's answer:

[image: Hadoop v1 vs v2]

**HADOOP Version 1**

The JobTracker is responsible for resource management---managing the slave nodes--- major functions involve

- tracking resource consumption/availability
- job life-cycle management---scheduling individual tasks of the job, tracking progress, providing fault tolerance for tasks.

**Issues with Hadoop v1**
JobTracker is responsible for all spawned MR applications, it is a single point of failure---If JobTracker goes down, all applications in the cluster are killed. Moreover, if the cluster has a large number of applications, JobTracker becomes the performance bottleneck, to address the issues of scalability and job management Hadoop v2 was released.

**Hadoop v2**

The fundamental idea of YARN is to split the two major responsibilities of the Job-Tracker—that is, resource management and job scheduling/monitoring—into separate daemons: a global ResourceManager and a per-application ApplicationMaster (AM). The ResourceManager and per-node slave, the NodeManager (NM), form the new, and generic, operating system for managing applications in a distributed manner.

To interact with the new resourceManagement and Scheduling, A Hadoop YARN mapReduce Application is developed---MRv2 has nothing to do with the mapReduce programming API

**Application programmers will see no difference between MRv1 and MRv2, MRv2 is fully backward compatible**---Yes an application(.jar), can be run on both the frameworks without any change in code.

MapReduce was previously integrated in Hadoop Core---the only API to interact with data in HDFS. Now In Hadoop v2 it runs as a separate Application, Hadoop v2 allows other application programming frameworks---e.g MPI---to process HDFS data.

[image: Hadoop 1.0 vs 2.0]